# Cannot compute confidence interval in ordinal regression (rms::orm)

Tags: r, regression

I'm fitting an ordinal regression model using Frank Harrell's **`rms`** package. However, I'm unable to estimate the confidence interval for quantiles of interest.

```
## Non-repex
d <- datadist(df)
options(datadist="d")

f5.loglog <- orm(y ~ rcs(x1, 7)*rcs(x2, 5) + x3,
             data = df,
             family = 'loglog',
             scale = TRUE,
             tol = 1e-20,
             x = TRUE,
             y = TRUE)

qu <- Quantile(f5.loglog)
p50 <- function(x) qu(0.50, x)

p.50 <- Predict(f5.loglog,
      x1,
      x2,
      x3 = c(-10, 12.6),
      fun = p50,
      conf.int = TRUE,
      np = 60)
```

`Predict` with `conf.int = TRUE` produces the following error:

```
Error in approx(c(cumprob(intercepts + lpm), 0), values, xout = cumprob(inverse(1 -  : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
In addition: Warning message:
In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)) :

 Error in approx(c(cumprob(intercepts + lpm), 0), values, xout = cumprob(inverse(1 -  : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
```

The sample size is quite large at 250,000 and the error only occurs when calculating confidence interval on any quantile (the mean produces no errors). Using quantile regression and the same number of knots, also produces no errors.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: That is a highly complex model. I'm not surprised that a crossed spline model with seven and 3 degrees of freedom might be numerically unstable. (I suspect it is not supported by any underlying theory.) Why don't you try estimating a somewhat more parsimonious model? I had numerical (and interpretability) problems when using crossed rcs terms even using less complex designs with ten time that much data.